# How to preserve the global variables in the stack in MIPS when calling a function?

Tags: assembly, compiler-construction, mips, code-generation

I'm developing a compiler from a language that mixes C++ and Javascript to MIPS Assembly

**What's the best approach to preserve the global variables in the stack when calling one or more functions, including recursion?**

At the main function, global and local variables are at the stack, starting from $fp, and that part works well.
However, when calling another function, the methodology I'm using saves the return address $ra and sets new $fp and $sp.
That means I have no more access to old $fp addresses where my global variables were saved.
How to proceed?

The image below describes the process that I'm using. Image obtained from Prof. Sen lectures, from Berkley
[image: Prof. Koushik Sen - Berkley]

Comment: Then why put them there? If you had just statically allocated them, you wouldn't have this problem.

Comment: You mean allocating at the .data region?

Comment: they are global variables yes?  why are you trying to put them on the stack with the local variables?

Comment: Right! Now, I just have to know how to modify the .data content inside the .text, and my problem will be solved

Comment: If your language supports nested scopes and closures (like javascript), then using `.data` is actually the harder way to go. The easier implementation is to create an outer activation record to hold globals during runtime initialization.  Then globals become the "locals" of an implicit parameterless procedure that is the entire running program.  This saves a lot of special case code treating globals differently from variables in nested scopes. Performance difference is likely to be marginal. For some processors, direct addressing in .text is slower than register-offset addressing in an AR.

Comment: I was exactly following that approach you pointed out, @Gene. I was passing my globals as a set of implicit parameters when a function call occurs. However, It became a mess to manage that, so I'm trying to adapt the globals at the .data segment, using the $gp, but still haven't got any success in modifying the .data segment inside .text

Comment: Well, if it's a mess, then the rest will be a mess because the outer scope is just another scope.

Comment: Solved! Thanks y'all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I put the globals at the .data segment

Here is how I access and modify their content

```
data
   globalVariable:  .word  10

.text

   #access
   lw $a0, globalVariable 

   #modify
   la $a0, globalVariable #get address
   li $a1, 11 #new value
   sw $a1 0($a0) #save new value

   lw $a2, globalVariable  #get new value
```